# Gamma correction with Pillow Image turning to Grayscale

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, plotly-dash, opencv

Trying to perform gamma correction on an image in a dash app. But original color images turn to grayscale after going through my function.  I'm using Pillow `Image.new("P", ...)` for color instead of "L" which would be for gray scale. And if I use `Image.new("RGB",...)` the returned image is red. Please help.

```
def gamma_correct(gamma, url):
    im = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)
    
    gamma1 = gamma
    row = im.size[0]
    col = im.size[1]
    result_img1 = Image.new("RGB", (row, col))
    for x in range(1 , row):
        for y in range(1, col):
            r = pow(im.getpixel((x,y))[0]/255, (1/gamma1))*255
            g = pow(im.getpixel((x,y))[1]/255, (1/gamma1))*255
            b = pow(im.getpixel((x,y))[2]/255, (1/gamma1))*255
            result_img1.putpixel((x,y)[0], int(r))
            result_img1.putpixel((x,y)[1], int(g))
            result_img1.putpixel((x,y)[2], int(b))
```

Comment: `P` means palette. I doubt you want that. and you mixed up the indices. and you have loops touching individual pixels, when this could be expressed in one expression using numpy

Comment: I tried pretty much all the modes available and couldn't get it to return gamma corrected original color image. It only returns grayscale version.

Comment: the inner loop body only touches [0] of each pixel, which is the red component. and your loops start at 1, while pixel coordinates start at 0. and all the other stuff (requests, figure, ...) are a distraction. write a function that takes an image and returns an image, and does nothing but change the gamma.

Comment: I updated my code. Is this what you mean?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bear in mind "P" and "RGB" are not the same. P is palette mode, and is limited to 256 colours.

Colour images have these dimensions: (width, tall, channels), with channels usually being = 3.

It seems like you are saving the image, with all colour values in a single channel, meaning you end up with an image like (width, tall, channels) with channel = 1.
This is also the reason why you get a red image when you use Image.new("RGB",...), since your image has data only in the first channel (R)

---

@ChristophRackwitz is correct in both his comments. Most often, libraries handling images actually handle the dimensions (height, width, channels), so if you load an image from disk which is, say, (1920,1080,3), the object in memory actually has dimensions (1080,1920,3). Additionally, some software (like opencv) even treat channels as BGR isntead of RGB by default

RGB images have 3 channels, which are the values of each colour. This means that for each pixel in the image, there are **3** colour values, one for red channel (R), one for green (G) and one for blue (B)

try debugging the image modification process, i.e:

```
for x in range(1 , row):
    for y in range(1, col):
            print(im.getpixel(x,y))
            r = pow(im.getpixel((x,y))[0]/255, (1/gamma1))*255
            g = pow(im.getpixel((x,y))[1]/255, (1/gamma1))*255
            b = pow(im.getpixel((x,y))[2]/255, (1/gamma1))*255
            print(im.getpixel(x,y))
```

The two print statements will print a 3-dimension array. Check that the values of each channel are as expected, both before and after

Comment: So if I used Image.new("L"...) everything works as expected but of course it's in gray scale. How could I go about keeping the original color?

Comment: **if** you mean to specify a `shape` in the *numpy* sense, it's `(height, width, channels)`, note the order of height then width, not width then height.

Comment: as for how to make it color... I hinted at that already. your code is incomplete. you need to handle the green and blue values of each pixel too. you haven't done that.

Comment: Obviously new to image processing and have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @moe92 edited my answer to add more information

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you are only passing one channel (that's R) parameter to the `putpixel()` method.
You need to pass a tuple of RGB values.

```
def gamma_correct(gamma, path):
    im = Image.open(path)
    gamma1 = gamma
    row = im.size[0]
    col = im.size[1]
    result_img1 = Image.new(mode="RGB", size=(row, col), color=0)
    for x in range(row):
        for y in range(col):
            r = pow(im.getpixel((x, y))[0] / 255, (1 / gamma1)) * 255
            g = pow(im.getpixel((x, y))[1] / 255, (1 / gamma1)) * 255
            b = pow(im.getpixel((x, y))[2] / 255, (1 / gamma1)) * 255
            # add
            color = (int(r), int(g), int(b))
            result_img1.putpixel((x, y), color)
    #show
    result_img1.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

One can

1. use LUT to implement gamma correction with `PIL`, using `ImageFilter.Color3DLUT.generate()` to generate the LUT using the `lambda` function as callback,

OR

2. use the `point()` method from `Image` class,

no need to iterate over pixels.

```
γ = 0.4
img = Image.open('dark_house.png') # open the image
```

With LUT:

```
LUT = ImageFilter.Color3DLUT.generate((11,11,11), lambda r, g, b: (r**γ, g**γ, b**γ))
img_out = img.filter(LUT)
```

Plot the input / output images:

```
plt.imshow(np.hstack((np.array(img), np.array()))), plt.axis('off')
plt.title('original and γ-corrected image', size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use the `point()` method from `Image` just with a single line of code:

```
img_out = img.point(lambda x: ((x/255)**γ)*255)
```

again plot as above to obtain the following output:

[image]

You can implement the same with the function `γ_correct()` using `opencv-python`'s `cv2.LUT()` to get similar output, too.

```
def γ_correct(img, γ):
    table = [((i / 255) ** γ) * 255 for i in range(256)]
    table = np.array(table, np.uint8)
    return cv2.LUT(img, table)

img = np.array(img)
img_out = γ_correct(img, γ)
```

Plot as above

[image]

One can compare the efficiency of the implementation with `time.time()`.